# Using php constants in twig as commonly used in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, twig, twig-extension

The default site that comes with yii2 has an about page with the following php code in it.

```
<code><?= __FILE__ ?></code>
```

Is it possible to do the same using twig syntax?

I have tried `{{ __FILE__ }}` and `{{ constant(__FILE__) }}` but neither of these worked, with the latter producing errors of `constant(): Couldn't find constant`.

Comment: Why would u need this? Even if this would work, the constant would resolve in a random template name in which the twig code was compiled. What's the goal u'r after?

Comment: Did you try passing the parameter from the controller to the view?

Comment: @DarkBee I was looking to convert the default templates that come with yii2 from php to twig as an example for myself and potentially others.

Comment: @nicolascolman I'm not 100% sure what you mean, do you have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score -2):

Try passing the parameter from the controller to the view.

Example code:

```
//Your view 
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Array(array(
    'index' => 'Hello {{ __FILE__ }}!',
));

//Your controller (see the second parameter in 'render')
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);    
echo $twig->render('index', array('__FILE__' =>  __FILE__ ));
```

Comment: This will return controller path instead of view path.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote but the OP never said what path is he looking for.

Comment: He want the same result as in PHP view, so obviously he wants a path of view. That is the point of magic constants.